# Create a dictionary of dictionaries from a Django queryset

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-queryset

I am currently creating a dictionary of querysets like this:

```
def get_type_dicts(self):
    types = BadgeType.objects.all()
    return {t.name : self.get_queryset().get_type(t) for t in types}
```

EDIT: this method is part of `BadgeManager(models.Manager)`, where:

```
class Badge(models.Model):
    ...
    badge_type = models.ForeignKey(BadgeType)
```

resulting in something like this:

```
{'Award': [<Badge: Copy of Copy of Blenbade>], 
 'Achievement': [<Badge: Copy of Blenbade>, <Badge: regergg>], 
 'Talent': [<Badge: Blender Brown Belt>, <Badge: Blender Blue Belt>, <Badge: Copy of Blender Blue Belt>, <Badge: fgdfgf Blender Blue Belt>, <Badge: Copy of Blender Brown Belt>, <Badge: Copy of fgdfgf Blender Blue Belt really long name >, <Badge: Copy of Blender Blue Beltcv x>, <Badge: regerggsdvsdv>]
}
```

How do I get something like this?

```
    {'Award': {'Attribute1': "something",
               'Attribute2': 27,
               'queryset': [<Badge: Copy of Copy of Blenbade>]
              },
     'Achievement': {'Attribute1': "somethingelse",
               'Attribute2': 99658,
               'queryset': [<Badge: Copy of Blenbade>, <Badge: regergg>]
              },
     etc...
   }
```

EDIT 2: or even more simple, based on Shang's comment:

```
    [ 
      {'type': <BadgeType: Talent>,
       'queryset': [<Badge: Copy of Copy of Blenbade>]
      },
      {'type': <BadgeType: Achievement>,
       'queryset': [<Badge: Copy of Blenbade>, <Badge: regergg>]
      },
      etc...
    ]
```

These attributes are all from the BadgeType model, so they could be found the same as `t.name`:

```
t.icon
t.description
```

etc.

EDIT: BadgeType model:

```
class BadgeType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    icon = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    ....
```

Comment: You need to show us the BadgeType model. We don't know where are `Award`, `Achievement` come from.

Comment: Sorry, I added more details, including BadgeType model and Badge.  But those come from t.name (BadgeType.name)

Comment: Then you are on the right track, have you tried to do

`return {t.name : {'name': t.name,
                           'icon': t.icon,
                           'description': t.description,
                            'queryset': self.get_queryset().get_type(t)} for t in types}`?

Comment: Thanks!  Can you post this as an answer?  Also, seems like rather than passing fields, I could just pass the object itself, `t` and get the fields as I need them in the context?

Comment: In addition, would it be easier to send as a list now? since I don't need a dict with the label 't.name' since I'm passing the object itself and can get the name form the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, just do:

```
return {t.name : {'name': t.name, 
                  'icon': t.icon,
                  'description': t.description,
                  'queryset': self.get_queryset().get_type(t)
                 }
        for t in types}
```

But this is not necessary at all, django has some useful database lookups that are really handy. You don't even need the code `get_queryset().get_type(t)`, you could just do:

```
t.badge_set.all()
```

Here's the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/relations/#related-objects-reference) that describes the `RelatedManager` usage, by default you use `badge_set` manager to do reverse lookups.

So in short, if you want to do something with the `BadgeType` objects, all you need is `types = BadgeType.objects.all()`, everything else comes with it.

You only pass your `types` queryset to the template, then in your template, do:

```
{% for badge_type in types %}
    <ul>{{ badge_type.name }}</ul>
    {% for badge in badge_type.badge_set.all %}
        <li>{{ badge.<attribute> }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: But if I use `t.badge_set.all()` they will all be in the same queryset right? I want them separated by `BadgeType`, because I want my template to be able to display them in groups (in completely different <ul> elements) according to their `BadgeType`.

Comment: It's not the same queryset. Here `t` is each `BadgeType` taken from `types`, and `t.badge_set.all()` returns all the `Badge` that has the foreign key `t`. I updated my answer just to help you a little more.

Comment: Thank you for the education, I understand now. This is obviously what I should be doing!